# How to extract this date format in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml structure:

```
 <Date>Mon, 11 Aug 2009 13:15:10 GMT</Date>
```

i want to extract only 13:15 or '13' and '15'. What is the best way to do that using xslt

Comment: yes, in that case its retriving substring after :, here I cant use that

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple modification from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509649/how-to-extract-this-format-in-xslt/3510540#3510540) in your previous question so all the same there mentioned restrictions apply here also.

```
<xsl:variable name="time" select="substring(Date, string-length(substring-before(Date, ':') - 1, 5)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XPath 2.0, you could use tokenize():

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Date>Mon, 11 Aug 2009 13:15:10 GMT</Date>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Date">
     <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(tokenize(.,' ')[5],':')[position() &lt; 3]"/>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
13 15
```